# Attribute <A> link for radiobutton not working in Chrome

Tags: html

`<a>` link for radion button is not working in Chrome. My code:

```
<td width='7%' bgcolor='#E8E8E8'>
  <a href='issue.php?admin=Yes&&user=$user'>
    <input type='radio' name='admin$user' $adminright />Y
  </a>
</td>
```

When the user clicks on the option button it should take to issue.php. This works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: why do you think this should work?

Comment: it was working in firefox, so i did not bother abt it. pls let me knw how can make it working

Answer (score 3):

You'll need JavaScript to redirect a user when he clicks on a form control other than a submit button.

However, think for a second, that's *not what the user expects to happen*. A radio button is expected to make a single selection out of a group of related options. It's *not* expected for the control to take you to a different page.

Instead, consider an actual form, with a submit button.

Comment: i need it without submit button. by clicking on radio button it should auto directs to next page, pls let me know how..!